# What's the equivalent for PostgreSQL 'localtimestamp' in JavaDB - Derby?

Tags: postgresql, migration, derby

Is there something simiar?

I have this definition

```
create table xyz ( 
    fecha_alta timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT localtimestamp,
    ....
)
```

I tried to execute the same in Derby, but it complains with:

> *Error: Syntax error: Encountered "localtimestamp" at line 3, column 41.*

What's the equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derby doesn't have time zones in it's datatype TIMESTAMP and it doesn't have a "localtimestamp" either. Just use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/